# Meteor: How to point a template prototype at another template?

Tags: meteor

I have a feeling that it must be possible to point to template helpers from one template to another. Does anyone know how to do this?

I see in the console that I have access to the Template I want: i.e. Template.Users_edit_page.

And it looks like there is a __helpers object with all the templates defined (Template.Users_edit_page.__helpers).

How can I do something along the lines of:

`Template.User_form.prototype.helpers = Template.Users_edit_page.helpers__`

and then ideally any helper called from the User_form template (which is a child of the Users_edit_page) would run the Users_edit_page template helper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I fully encourage digging into the internals of a framework to better understand what it is doing, directly linking into implementation details like this (e.g.  `*.__helpers`) is generally not a good idea, as framework developers may change implementation details breaking your code.

When you use the public APIs you can expect less breaking changes, and advanced notice before that happens (e.g., APIs marked for future deprecation).

As I mentioned in your other question the most flexible approach to sharing helpers across templates is with [Template.registerHelper](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_registerhelper).

However if you need something more targeted you can define your functions as standalone javascript functions:

```
passwordSecure = function(password) {
  return password.length > 8;
};
validEmail = function(email) {
  return email.contains('@');
};
```

Then include them as helpers in all the templates you want them in like this:

```
Template.User_form.helpers({
  'passwordSecure': passwordSecure,
  'validEmail':  validEmail, 
});
```